# Wait for JavaScript scripts to load in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding a plugins system to a program and I want the user to be able to include files and raw information. I have a problem, however with loading the scripts. I want to wait for all the scripts to load (I don't know the number of them, however). An example is this:

Plugins.json:

```
{"include":["script1.json", "script2.json"]}
```

main file ("pluginsFile" variable is the content of "Plugins.json"):

```
/*I have a system that lets the user import the plugins file*/
loadedScripts = 0;
if (pluginsFile.include){
    for (i of pluginsFile.include){
        var scriptToAdd = document.createElement("script");
        scriptToAdd.src = pluginsFile.include[i];
        scriptToAdd.addEventListener("load", function(){
            loadedScripts++;
        })
        document.head.appendchild(scriptToAdd);
    }
    while (loadedScripts < document.querySelectorAll("head > script")){//Assume that I only have the scripts I want to add inside the head}
    //After all the scripts loaded
    console.log("loaded");
}
```

However, when I import the file, the while loop doesn't stop and the tab lags. I want to wait for all the scripts I insert into `<head>` to be loaded and then continue. I this possible?

Comment: Have you tried window.addEventListener('load', your-function-here)?

Comment: doesn't this event get triggered at the first load of the document?

Comment: document.querySelector() returns 1 single nodeElement and document.querySelectorAll() an array of elements. Maybe the problem is there in your while loop? And I would try this way: `while (loadedScripts <= document.querySelectorAll("head > script").length) { ... }`

Comment: Oops... Sorry, no, I have `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: You are burning your CPU here because you constantly query the number of loaded scripts. Your browser might not have the time to load scripts because it is busy with checking if all scripts haven been loaded. Try to put a sleep in your while loop (by using a `Promise` or switching to `setInterval`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Promises you can wait for each script to be loaded and do something after that.

Create a function that returns a Promise. Put the creation of your script tag, the setting of the `src`, listening for the `load` event, and appending the tag to the `<head>` inside of the promise. Modify the `load` event that it resolves the promise whenever the load event fires. Resolving tells the promise it is done.

```js
const loadScript = src => new Promise(resolve => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
  document.head.appendchild(script);
});
```

Then `map` over each file source in your `pluginsFile.include` array and call the function that loads the script inside of the promise. The result should now be an array of promises.

We'll want to wait before continuing until all promises in that array are resolved.
We can do this with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). The logic that comes after the `Promise.all()` in the `then()` method will be executed once all scripts have been loaded.

```js
if (pluginsFile.include.length) {
  const loadingScripts = pluginsFile.include.map(loadScript);
  Promise.all(loadingScripts).then(() => {
    console.log('loaded');
  });
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I have been trying to fix this for 4 hours. I was scared to ask in StackOverflow because I had a history of asking low questions and you solved this in some minutes!!!

Comment: @Ath.Bar. You're very welcome. Good job posting your question regardless of previous posts! Keep it up!